# How do I create CSV that an API can parse from a string?

Tags: javascript, csv, qualtrics, encodeuricomponent

I am looking to create a CSV from a string that I can send to a Qualtrics API to run a call. The call I am trying to run is at this URL:

https://api.qualtrics.com/reference#start-response-import

The call asks for a CSV file, but I don't know how to give it a CSV; I only know how to download that CSV using

```
var CSVAsString = '1,2,3'
var CSV = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURIComponent(CSVAsString)
```

How would I send a CSV instead of a string of text that can be used to download the CSV? (I don't have trouble sending it, just have trouble creating a CSV document that the APIs can read)

Answer (score 0):

Duh it should be

```
'data:text/csv'
```

NOT

```
'data:attachment/csv'
```

Answered my own question!